# How do I pass params to my devise_invitable controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-invitable

I have created an invitation controller that is quite vanilla:

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def new
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

And I created a link that triggers that request like so:

```
<%= link_to "Invite #{@profile.name}", new_user_invitation_path(email: @profile.email), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
```

The issue I am having is that when I get thrown into pry in that action, it doesn't show me that `email` parameter.

```
> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"invitations", "action"=>"new"} permitted: false>
```

How can I send params with that `InvitationsControler#New` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `new_user_invitation_path` corresponds to a `GET` request to a new invitation object, which generates a new form.

The solution is to create another action in another controller then simply call it with a `method: :post` like so:

```
<%= link_to "Invite #{@profile.name}", invite_path(@profile), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you SURE you are ready to invite #{@profile.name}?"}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
```

That works like a charm.

Comment: thanks for the post! I know it's been a long time ago, but how did you create an action in a different controller and subsequently still managed to use the devise_invitable create? Or did you do something different?